# Display matrix data

Tags: java, matrix

I want to display matrix values just like a matrix

just like this

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

When I make this code, it appears vertically

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++)
                    System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println` prints a line **and** a break line. You would want to use `System.out.print` that only prints the data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But now the problem is that all the data in the same *row* is printed with no space. You can use `System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");` but that's a little clumsy. The best option would be to use `System.printf` to allow formatting of the text that will be printed on the console:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
        //assuming mat[i][j] content is int...
        System.out.printf("%3d", mat[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

More info about formatting with `System.out.printf`: [Format String syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Use `print` in inner loop which will print one row in a single line. Use `println` in outer loop which will separate each row.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++)
        System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: *Try this*? At least explain **why** it should be like that.